# LaTeX to Customized LaTeX file conversion using htlatex

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

I would like to convert `LaTeX` to `Customized LaTeX code` using `htlatex`. It's possible in `tex4ht`? Our ultimate goal is `natbib` cross-link need to convert to `without \cite` tag, `\def` command need to explanation and many more. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\def\myitalicbold#1{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\title{Article title here}
\author{chen}
\maketitle
Sample Text here with \myitalicbold{bold-and-italic} and normal text here.

According to the consolidated banking statistics from BIS, the balance of the external assets of global banks at end-June 2012 has expanded 2.9 times from 2000. Furthermore, the country-level aggregate statistics of \citet{Lane/Milesi-Ferretti:08} indicate that the stock of cross-border banking is more than 50 percent of the overall amount of international holdings.
\end{document}
```

**My Required Output is:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\def\myitalicbold#1{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\title{Article title here}
\author{chen}
\maketitle
Sample Text here with \textbf{\textit{bold-and-italic}} and normal text here.

According to the consolidated banking statistics from BIS, the balance of the external assets of global banks at end-June 2012 has expanded 2.9 times from 2000. Furthermore, the country-level aggregate statistics of Lane, A. and Milesi-Ferretti, S. (2008) indicate that the stock of cross-border banking is more than 50 percent of the overall amount of international holdings.
\end{document}
```

Comment: for this some other tool be better suited, `tex4ht` can't preserve LaTeX macros, it just translate them to some output format

Comment: @michal: Could you please provide other tool weblink or guideline please.

Comment: perhaps Sed? http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html